# При обращении к URL с помощью HttpWebRequest получаю HTTP 400 error

Tags: c#, кэширование, httpwebrequest

Есть 3 метода, в каждом методе происходит обращение к разным урлам, в каждом методе создается новый объект HttpWebRequest, но при третьем обращении к УРЛ, я получаю ошибку 400. Только третий метод обращается к УРЛ без тела запроса. 
Вот сам код методов:

Первый

```
public static string MailChimp_CreateNewCampaing(int randomNumberName, string listID, string previewText, string fromName, string fromEmail)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(mailChimp_createNewCampaing);
        HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization:" + "anystring " + Constants.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

        string json = "{" + "\n" +
                            "\"type\": \"" + "regular\"," + "\n" +
                            "\"recipients\":{" + "\n" +
                                "\"list_id\": \"" + listID + "\"" + "\n" +
                            "}," + "\n" +
                            "\"settings\": {" + "\n" +
                                "\"subject_line\": \"" + "Subject test auto test " + randomNumberName + "\"," + "\n" +
                                "\"preview_text\": \"" + previewText + "\"," + "\n" +
                                "\"title\": \"" + "Title auto Test " + randomNumberName + "\"," + "\n" +
                                "\"from_name\": \"" + fromName + "\"," + "\n" +
                                "\"reply_to\": \"" + fromEmail + "\"," + "\n" + 
                                "\"template_id\": " + Constants.MAILCHIMP_TEMPLATE_ID + "\n" +
                            "}\n" +
                        "}";

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Json for Request: \n" + json);

        using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string respStr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(respStr);
        string id = (string)jObject.SelectToken("id");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Campaing id: " + id);
        resp.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return id;
    }
```

Второй метод

```
public static string MailChimp_CreateNewList(int randomNumberForNames, string fromName, string email, string subject)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(mailChimp_CreateList);
        HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization:" + "anystring " + Constants.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

        string json = "{" + "\n" +
                            "\"name\": \"List for auto test " + randomNumberForNames + "\",\n" +
                            "\"contact\": {\n" +
                                   "\"company\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"address1\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"address2\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"city\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"state\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"zip\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"country\": \"" + "\",\n" +
                                   "\"phone\": \"" + "\"\n" +
                               "},\n" +
                               "\"permission_reminder\": \"Test\",\n" +
                               "\"campaign_defaults\": {\n" +
                                    "\"from_name\": \"" + fromName + "\",\n" +
                                    "\"from_email\": \"" + email + "\",\n" +
                                    "\"subject\": \"" + subject + "\",\n" +
                                    "\"language\": \"US\"\n" +
                                "},\n" +
                                "\"email_type_option\": " + true + "\n" +
                                "}";
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(json);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string respStr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(respStr);
        string listID = (string)jobject.SelectToken("id");
        response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        return listID;
    }
```

Вот третий метод с ошибокой:

```
    public static void MailChimp_SendCampaing(string campaingId)
        {
            string url = String.Format(mailChimp_SentCampaingPattern, campaingId);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Send URL: " + url);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization:" + "anystring " + Constants.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.GetRequestStream();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Respone code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
            if((int)response.StatusCode != (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
            {
                Assert.Fail("Error with sending campaing, Error code: " + (int)response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
```

Но когда использую этот урл из постмана, то все работает ОК. Возможно нужно просто почтисть кеш перед запросом, тогда подскажите как?

Comment: Поправил вам форматирование кода.

Comment: Ох как вы себе мозг мучаете с этим JSON... Не уж то нельзя воспользоваться нормальной сериализацией/десериализацией? Смотреть на такое страшно!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Все равно ошибка останется при обращении к URL.

Comment: А я и не говорил, что это поможет. Я говорю сейчас о чистоте кода. Вам же будет приятней работать с классом и его объектами, чем с простым текстом. Ну да ладно, дело каждого. По вопросу - установите Fiddler и отловите запрос отправляемый через Postman и через ваше приложение, ну и сравните их.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Может быть ты знаешь как почистить кеш Http?WebRequest? Потому что эта программа не показывает полный урл, плюс в ней все запросы со статусами 200, хотя в коде я вижу ошибку 400.

Comment: Вроде постман ContentType подставляет по дефолту, в третьем методе он у вас не указан

Comment: @morphey83 в коде это было указано, но здесь не перенес, но и с этой строкой тоже не работает.

Comment: Полный URL в этой программе (я надеюсь мы про Fiddler сейчас говорим), это host+само значение URL ([пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43pwi.png)). Если вы не видите нужного запроса, то значит делаете что то не так, отлов HTTPS трафика включили в настройках? А по поводу "кэша" - на сколько я знаю, в HttpWebRequest как такового его нету и чистить там нечего. Ищите проблему в другом месте.

Comment: и еще базовый вопрос : вы уверены, что через постман вы дергаете методом POST ?

Comment: @morphey83 да, через постман я тоже дергаю методом POST.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Он отлавливает запросы к тому ресурсу к которому я обращаюсь, но сыылка указана только tunel to:host:port и на этом все, хотя я трижды обращался, и различить где какой не смог.

Comment: А порт у вас небось 443? Если да, то как я и говорил, включите отлов HTTPS в настройках и после этого tunel to... будут дальше ваши запросы. Вы кстати уверены в этой строке `string url = String.Format(mailChimp_SentCampaingPattern, campaingId);`? Выдает ли она вам нужный результат? Кстати, на сколько я понял вы используете [этот](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/) сервис, так может скажете что именно хотите сделать и мы попробуем с документацией свериться?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, использую этот сервис, план такой, создать лист, доабвиь в него subscriber, создать кемпейн (добавить в кемпейн новосозданный лист), и отправить кемпейн. Вот на момент отправки кемпейна получаю ошибку.

Comment: Судя по документации вам достаточно отправить на `https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/{id}/actions/send` post запрос, без указания типа или чего либо еще. В ответ вы должны получить JSON, если ошибка, то примерно [следующего](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#errors) содержания. Что у вас пишет в теле ответа вместе с ошибкой?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я не получаю тела ошибки, только Http ответ ошибки 400. А через Postman ошибки нет ни какой (Хотя используется тот же Урл, который и в коде).

Comment: @MainStar тела ошибки вы не получите тк 400 ошибка говорит о том что сервер либо не отвечает либо не смог определить маршрут по данному url. В плане кэша сервер не держит кэш это не браузер и чистить тут нечего, если сомневаетесь отправьте 3-й запрос первым)) Попробуйте пустой объект передать как правило post методы по Rest философии должны передавать объект. В случае с отсутствием или не соответствием типа принимаемых данных так же может возвращаться 400 было не 1 раз

Comment: @Bulat дело в том, что я создаш отдельный проект, что бы проверить этот запрос, и отправил его, и он сработал нормально, компантя отправилась, и статуч запроса бвл 204, по этому я так и грешил на кеш.

Comment: @Bulat а по поводу передачи пустого объекта в Потс запрос, то так же не сработало, но все же спасибо)